# Not getting any output when using filestreams in java

Tags: java

I've been stuck on this one section of my programming homework for a while and I can't seem to understand what's wrong. I'm supposed to use scanners to take in grades from an input file and put them into an array (not ArrayList). Then it should calculate the average, maximum and minimum and then print those out into a new separate text file. The program runs with no errors, but I get no output in my output file. Am I overthinking this?
Excuse the messy code, I'll fix it later.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class GradeStatistics {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner scanNum = new Scanner(new File("grades.txt"));
    double total = 0;
    int numStudents = 0;

    //traverse the file, counting the number of lines and save into numStudents
    while(scanNum.hasNextInt())
    {
        numStudents += 1;
    }

    int grades[] = new int[numStudents];    //create grades array

    Scanner scan2 = new Scanner("grades.txt");

    //populate the array
    for(int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++)
    {
        grades[i] = scan2.nextInt();
    }

    int max = grades[0];
    int min = grades[0];

    //find the max and min
    for(int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++)
    {
        total = total + grades[i];
        if(grades[i] > max)
        max = grades[i];
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++)
    {
        if(grades[i] < min)
            min = grades[i];
    }
    double average = total / grades.length;     //calculate the average

    //create a new file "results.txt" to print our results
    FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream("results.txt");
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(f));
    System.out.printf("The average is: %.2f\n", average);
    System.out.println("The minimum is: " + min);
    System.out.println("The maximum is: " + max);
    scan2.close();
    scanNum.close();

}
```

}

Comment: You aren't reading anything out of the file.  hasNextInt() is a boolean function that tells you if the next input can be interpreted as an integer.  It does not actually read the value or advance the file pointer.  So this statement: grades[i] = scan2.nextInt(); returns true or false, it does not return an integer.

Comment: How does scan2.nextInt() return true or false? I'm using nextInt() not hasNextInt().

Comment: Use print statements to check the intermediate values.

Answer (score 0):

This is an endless loop because it does not advance the file pointer:

```
while(scanNum.hasNextInt())
{
    numStudents += 1;
}
```

This line contains also an error:

```
Scanner scan2 = new Scanner("grades.txt");
```

Should be

```
Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(new File("grades.txt"));
```